# How to update a table data based on selected table row in jQuery?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am having difficulties updating table data based on a table row selected by a user in jQuery.

Whenever the user clicks a row I want the data in the row to be shown in `input` fields. When I click edit button it will enable the `input` fields so that I can edit the table data and click the save button to finally update it.

Comment: Hi Nick, can you please explain what the exact problem is? Doesn't it work as expected, do you see error messages in the console of you browser?

Comment: When I put your code into a fiddle, everything appears to be working fine - except that the Save button does not get enabled, but that was because I could not be troubled to embed jQueryUI as well, so that the `datepicker` line threw an error. That line commented out, and the Save button got enabled, and clicking on it showed the alert fine as well.

Comment: Also the `#save` button doesn't do anything because the click handler attached to it is looking for a `tr` element parent, which the button doesn't have.

Comment: Hi, @Sven van de Scheur, I dont see error in my console but the save button is not working whenever I want to update the table data selected by a user

Comment: HI, @CBroe yes when you click save an alert will be prompted, but it doesn't update the data in the table whenever a user change it

Comment: Well if the handler was triggered by clicking the Save button, then what do you expect `$(this).closest("tr")` to select? The button itself is not a `tr` element, and none of its ancestors are either.

Comment: I thought that $(this).closest("tr") will respond to this #recentCasesTable tr". Any idea sir how can I solve this issue? By the way you can check the full code here https://jsfiddle.net/oqrngk02/

Comment: `$("#save , #recentCasesTable tr")` the comma inside the string means jquery will add an event to `#save` and an event to (every) `#recentCasesTable tr`.   So clicking on a row will also call the save function.   It *might* be that you mean `$("#save", "#recentCasesTable tr")` which would be the same as `$("#recentCasesTable tr #save")` but as your #save is not on a tr, this would then never fire.

Comment: In your snippet, when you click a row, you can see "helooo" being added to the row when it copies the values.

Comment: Hi @freedomn-m, any idea sir how can I access `#recentCasesTable tr` so that it will respond to `$(this).closest("tr")` sir.

Comment: @freedomn-m I added my updated code to JSFiddle. Here is the [link](https://jsfiddle.net/oqrngk02/) sir. For now the code can only edit the DepartmentCase for testing purposes

Comment: Change `$("#save , #recentCasesTable tr")` to just `$("#save")` as the comma is confusing you and not relevant.  Then get the "active" row with `var currentRow = $("#recentCasesTable tr.highlighted");` as there's no "relative DOM navigation" from the button to a random row.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to "remember" which row was clicked to fill the inputs.

One option would be to use an immutable field such as a database ID - a field that gets copied to your inputs, but can't be changed by the user.  Alternatively, set a property on the row so that it can be found again.

When #save is clicked, you can then update the previously remembered `tr`.

In fact, you are already doing this:

```
$(this).addClass('highlighted');
```

So your save button just needs to get the highlighted row and update the table:

```
  $("#save").click(function() {
    var currentRow = $("#recentCasesTable tr.highlighted");
    currentRow.find("td:eq(0)").text($("#departmentCase").val()); 
    //.. other fields

    $("#departmentCase").prop('disabled', true).val('');
    //.. other fields
  });
```

Updated snippet, for simplicity/demo, I've removed the other columns from the edit:

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  //Highlight row when clicked
  $('#recentCasesTable tr').click(function() {
    $('#recentCasesTable tr').removeClass('highlighted');
    $(this).addClass('highlighted');

    var currentRow = $(this).closest("tr");
    $("#departmentCase").val(currentRow.find("td:eq(0)").text());
  });

  //Check if a row is highlighted
  $("#edit").click(function() {
    if (!$('input').val()) {
      alert("Please click a row.");
    } else {
      $("#departmentCase").prop('disabled', false);
      $("#edit").prop('disabled', true);
      $("#save").prop('disabled', false);
      $("#cancel").prop('disabled', false);
      
      $("#departmentCase").val("for testing");
    }
  });

  $("#save").click(function() {
    var currentRow = $("#recentCasesTable tr.highlighted");
    currentRow.find("td:eq(0)").text($("#departmentCase").val());
    $("#departmentCase").prop('disabled', true).val('');
  });
});
```

```css
tr.highlighted td { color: rebeccapurple }
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.6.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.13.2/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.13.2/themes/base/jquery-ui.min.css" />
<p id="demo"></p>
<table id="recentCasesTable">
  <tr>
    <th>Department Case Number#</th>
    <th>Department</th>
    <th>Charge</th>
    <th>Lab Case #</th>
    <th>Incident Report Date</th>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>409-14595-2607-075</td>
    <td>FORI-PALMDALE</td>
    <td>BURGLARY</td>
    <td>13-000069</td>
    <td>05/08/2013</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>567-28904-2607-075</td>
    <td>FORI-PALMDALE</td>
    <td>ILLEGAL DUMPING</td>
    <td>10-000869</td>
    <td>05/08/2013</td>
  </tr>
</table>

<fieldset>
  <legend><b>Case Details</b></legend>
  <table id="caseDetails">
    <tr>
      <td>Department Case #</td>
      <td><input type="text" id="departmentCase" name="departmentCase#" disabled="disabled" / value="" /></td>
    </tr>
  </table>
  <br/>

  <button id="edit" name="edit" type="submit" value="edit">Edit</button>
  <button id="save" name="save" type="submit" value="save" disabled="disabled">Save</button>
  <button id="cancel" name="cancel" type="submit" value="cancel" disabled="disabled">Cancel</button>
</fieldset>
```

Comment: @fredomm-m Thank you so much sir for thoroughly explaining, I understand it now. It finally worked.

Comment: @fredomm-m Last question sir. What if I want to edit another `departmentCase`? What should I do?

Comment: Change `$("#departmentCase").attr("value", "newvalue")` to the correct: `$("#departmentCase").val("newvalue")` - updated the snippet.